# Angular 5 to access an external window object url which is opened by window open in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

Hi i have opened a window using angular 5 using the below method

```
 var opened = window.open("localhost:4200/#/url");
```

the above code will redirect to another external url. i want to access the redirect url.

i tried the below code

```
console.log(opened.location.href);
```

but is giving following like this

> about:blank

the same thing is working in javascript

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

i need to do the same in angular 5. is it possible to do.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the redirection is compliant with the Same-origin policy ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: yes i am using the same origin policy only but it is giving blank

Comment: here is the url of stackblitz   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqls9h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communication between two windows from the same origin can be done in multiple ways, one of these ways is, using localStorage or sessionStorage. Changes in localStore or sessionStorage variable's value can listen across the application in multiple windows.

So when you open a child window, start listening for storage variable change and as soon as child window loads, just set the newly loaded URL in local storage, so that parent can catch it. Finally, just remove the event listener.

Hope this helps.

**[Upadted solution, After reviewing your *stackblitz* link]:**

When we open a new window programmatically, we know that its initial URL state will be blank, then javascript comes into play and loads the requested URL. But, As we know Angular always has the problem in catching native javascript variable changes, the same thing happening here. Angular is only aware of initial state `blank`, but not the loaded URL, lately.

To solve this problem, Maybe you can use `window.OnChildWindowLoaded`.

**Parent:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  urlopened;
  opengoogle(){
    window.OnChildWindowLoaded = function (href) {
        console.log('Opened ' + href + ' successfully');
    };
    this.urlopened = window.open("https://stackblitz.com","");
  }
}
```

**Child:**

```
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    window.opener.OnChildWindowLoaded(location.href);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: i know i can do it by using storages but i tried by using location variables please see the code to better understand https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqls9h

Comment: What if the URL loaded in the child window is to an external Website, like authorizing a social service? I can't add my own code to this Web page.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Url by [router Event](https://angular.io/guide/router#summary) :

Like this:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Router, NavigationEnd,NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 
    `<a routerLink='A'>A</a>
    <a routerLink='B'>B</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

   ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
          if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log("NavigationStart",event.url)
        // alert('navigation succeeded');
      }
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log("NavigationEnd",event.url)
        // alert('navigation succeeded');
      }
    })
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  template: '<h1>A</h1>',
})
export class AComponent  {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  template: '<h1>B</h1>',
})
export class BComponent  {}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'A', component: AComponent },
  { path: 'B', component: BComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RootRoutingModule { }
```

Here you can see router url in both console.log.

Comment: i need the another window url . please see stackbliz to understand my problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqls9h